# Why is my CSS3 box shadow not working properly?

Tags: css

I'm using the newest version of Chrome and I simply cannot get the box shadow to display properly on my div when I use rounded corners..it looks like it's cut off or something, please see the screenshot below:

[image]

You can see the test site at http://chronologic.ath.cx/Gardner/

Thanks,

slashp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your CSS reset contains an `overflow: hidden` style which is causing your `div.container` to clip the shadow. You should just remove it, because I don't see anything in the selector that's worth applying such an overflow to:

```
html,
div,
span,
head,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
a,
font,
img,
small,
strong,
ol,
ul,
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I put it there because the jQuery gallery was making a scroll bar pop up for no reason when I would flip through the images.  I've removed it and everything appears to be working fine (minus the scroll bar issue, but the jQuery gallery is going away so I really don't care).  Thanks again!

Comment: It is not fair practice but you can use `overflow: hidden` for `html` tag only and horizontal scroll will be gone.